RequestBody object with single property spring-boot
Language: Kotlin, Spring version: 3.2.3
I have controller that gives an object with single property:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
class Test {

   @PostMapping("khar")
   fun khar(@RequestBody body: UserByTokenRequest): String {
       return body.apiToken
   }
}

class UserByTokenRequest(val apiToken: String)

And I call it but I get "Bad Request" with status code 400, the log of server is:

WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:247 - Resolved
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of
ir.police.policecore.userclass.model.dto.UserByTokenRequest
(although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object
value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)]

When I just add another property to "UserByTokenRequest" Or Just add @JsonProperty to the property, the problem will disappear, and I get my response.
I just wondering why it's not working with single property.

What are you posting to the controller?

Because in Kotlin, when you define a class with a single primary constructor parameter like UserByTokenRequest(val apiToken: String), it generates a class with a public final field and a constructor, but no default constructor or setter methods.

works fine for me. Do you have kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.24" in your gradle file?

Pls check if you have "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" in your dependencies list. This dependency allows Jackson deserialiser, that is used by default in spring boot, to work with Kotlin classes.
